# VBA - Trying to add incremented number when a new cell is filled

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, auto-increment, autofill

i'm new in excel, and I try to add a column that increments only when I select the right city in the list, so it will create a folder number...

The problem that I can't do this in formula is that when I sort the folders by city the numbers change...

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

- the first colum is the folder number
- the second is the number that I try to increment automatically
- the fourth is the city

https://i.stack.imgur.com/daNx6.png

Answer (score 0):

If the data starts in column A and it's always 1 digit you need to get, in column B use and drag down this formula:
`=RIGHT(A:A,1)`